# Custom disabled button with a gif overlay

Tags: html, css

I am interested in creating a `:disabled` button that has loading gif which follows the text of the button. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/roman_khrystynych/YTBLs/

The idea is that when a user clicks the button it begins showing a loading animation next to the changed text. In this format the button is disabled. I would like to use this format for all the buttons on the site which means that the text will quite often change.

Because of this I would like the button to be structured in a way that would automatically position the loading gif next to the text.

Any suggestions on how to format this button so that in disabled format it shows the animation gif right next to the text?

Answer (score 1):

You could use LABEL tags with a CSS background to go with the buttons. When the button is disabled, change the class name on the label to show the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<button>Submit<span> * </span></button>
```

Stick your graphic on/in the `<span>` tag.

Comment: I don't believe your HTML is valid.